# Amazon Web Services : Setting S3 policy to allow putObject and getObject but deny listBucket

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using getObject and putObject requests on Amazon S3 and in creating a policy for access to the bucket I discovered that if I don't allow listBucket I get an 'access denied' error.

The problem with this is that listBucket means a user can list the keys in a bucket and this presents
a security threat.

Is it possible to allow getObject and putObject without allowing listBucket?
or is there a workaround for this?

Here is the policy:

```
 {
 "Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
{
  "Sid": "Stmt##",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
    "s3:ListBucket"
  ],
  "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:s3:::myBucket"
  ]
},
{
  "Sid": "Stmt##",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
    "s3:GetObject",
    "s3:PutObject"
  ],
  "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:s3:::myBucket/*"
  ]
}
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [Get Object documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html):

> You need the `s3:GetObject` permission for this operation.  For more information, go to Specifying Permissions in a Policy in the Amazon Simple Storage Service Developer Guide. If the object you request does not exist, the error Amazon S3 returns depends on whether you also have the `s3:ListBucket` permission.

I've confirmed this behavior by editing a policy that was essentially identical to yours.

**I am able to get an existing object without trouble, whether or not I have the `s3:ListBucket` privilege**, as long as I have the `s3:GetObject` privilege.

The behavior changes only if I don't also have the `s3:ListBucket` privilege, and I request *an object that does not exist*.  In that case, S3 will not admit to me whether that object exists -- I'm denied access to knowledge about the existence of the object, since I'm not authorized to see the list.

Response for a valid request to a nonexistent object, *without* `s3:ListBucket`:

```
<Error>
 <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
 <Message>Access Denied</Message>
 <RequestId>xxxx</RequestId>
 <HostId>xxxx</HostId>
</Error>
```

Response for a valid request for the same nonexistent object, *with* `s3:ListBucket`:

```
<Error>
 <Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
 <Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
 <Key>fakefile.txt</Key>
 <RequestId>xxxx</RequestId>
 <HostId>xxxx</HostId>
</Error>
```

So, on objects that don't actually exist, "access denied" is the expected response without `s3:ListBucket`.  Otherwise, it works as expected.

Comment: Indeed this is true. Thanks